# Android: Error:Execution failed for task app:transformClassesWithPreJackPackagedLibrariesForDebug

Tags: android, android-studio, java-8

I got this error when I tried to run my Android program.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithPreJackPackagedLibrariesForDebug'.
>   java.lang.AssertionError: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: jayce/org/hamcrest/BaseDescription.jayce

here is my build.gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.surgical.decision"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    jackOptions {
        enabled true
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile files('libs/simple-xml-2.7.1.jar')
compile files('libs/log4j-1.2.17.jar')
compile files('libs/pddl4j-3.5.0.jar')
}
```

I have to enable jackOptions because there are a lot of function that I wrote in Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

I had that same problem. I believe that `com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2` is compiled with hamcrest and I think that `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1` also is compiled with hamcrest.  I believe the error message is telling you that the hamcrest package is contained in at least two of the compiled jar and it can't resolve the duplicate issue (even though they are the same version). It probably can't resolve the duplicate due to some Jack technicality.  To get around the problem, you just need to exclude it from one or the other:

i.e

```
`androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    exclude group: 'org.hamcrest', module: 'hamcrest-core'

})
```

or if you're not really using espresso-core, just delete the androidTestCompile line altogether.

In my situation, I also had to add:

```
exclude group: 'junit', module: 'junit'
```

because I was getting a slightly different error due to the inclusion of two different junit versions conflict.

The best technique for debugging these kinds of errors is by using gradle from a command line.

1. open command prompt
2. navigate to project directory (it contains gradlew.bat)
3. > gradlew app:androidDependencies